# Trying to insert multiple records into table with single insert statement but its throwing error

Tags: sql, oracle

Trying to insert multiple records into table with single insert statement but its throwing error . Is it correct method to do

> SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
> 00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
> *Cause:
> *Action:

```
insert into customers values (100356,'ramo',89638527410,to_date('13-04-2023','dd-mm-yyyy'),'ramo@gmail.com','Mexico')
 (100356,'ramo',89638527417,to_date('13-04-2023','dd-mm-yyyy'),'ramo@gmail.com','Finland')
 (100356,'ramo',89638527418,to_date('13-04-2023','dd-mm-yyyy'),'ramo@gmail.com','Ireland')
 (100356,'ramo',89638527419,to_date('13-04-2023','dd-mm-yyyy'),'ramo@gmail.com','Newjersey')
 (100356,'ramo',89638527414,to_date('13-04-2023','dd-mm-yyyy'),'ramo@gmail.com','rome')
 (100356,'ramo',89638527415,to_date('13-04-2023','dd-mm-yyyy'),'ramo@gmail.com','canada')
 (100356,'ramo',89638527416,to_date('13-04-2023','dd-mm-yyyy'),'ramo@gmail.com','Namabia')
 (100356,'ramo',89638527411,to_date('13-04-2023','dd-mm-yyyy'),'ramo@gmail.com','SouthAfrica')
 (100356,'ramo',89638527413,to_date('13-04-2023','dd-mm-yyyy'),'ramo@gmail.com','England')
 (100356,'ramo',89638527415,to_date('13-04-2023','dd-mm-yyyy'),'ramo@gmail.com','Ontario')
 (100356,'ramo',89638527416,to_date('13-04-2023','dd-mm-yyyy'),'ramo@gmail.com','London')
 (100356,'ramo',89638527414,to_date('13-04-2023','dd-mm-yyyy'),'ramo@gmail.com','Mexica');
```

Using ORACLE Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production

Comment: @tripleee I've worked with Oracle for 25 years and never knew about the INSERT ALL syntax. Thanks for teaching an old dog a new trick!

Comment: Thanks, but I'm only the messenger here; somebody posted the link as an answer (which was subsequently deleted as not really an answer) and I simply copied that into a close vote. If it solved your problem, please acknowledge the duplicate. Thanks again.